# splitting bash script arguments over "="

Tags: bash, parameters, sed

I have a bash script where you can specify options with "--option parameter":

```
if [ ${1:0:2} != '--' ] ; then 
    echo -e "Unrecognized option: $1\n$requestHelpMessage"; exit 1;
fi
if [ ! $2 ];
    then echo -e "Expected parameter for $1\n$requestHelpMessage"; exit 1;
fi
case ${1:2} in
    branch) # do something with $2 here
    batch) # do something with $2 here
    version) # do something with $2 here
    *) # you get the idea
esac
```

And I want to extend it to be able to handle "--option=parameter" as well. Is there an easy way to split over "=" without special-casing each one?

Comment: Just a comment, because it may not be useful to you, but parsing arguments is a pain and riddled with edge cases.  Better just to use the bash builtin getopts.

Comment: I was under the impression getopts was not so great at words, and I need this to replicate certain behavior of another script, so I don't have the freedom to use letters

Comment: That's totally true.  getopts doesn't really work for multiple character flags.  Check out my answer below about using getopt instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using getopt or making your own setup, try using "[getopt](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/extmisc.html#GETOPTY)".  It supports both long (word) and short (character) arguments.

Here's an example of it in use:

```
get_inputs () {
    set -- $( getopt -u -l class:,desc:,force,host:,help,verbose "c:d:fh:v?" "$@" )

    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do 
        case "$1" in
            -c|--class)
                CLASS=$2
                shift
                ;;
            -d|--desc)  
                DESCR=$2
                shift
                ;;
            -f|--force)
                FORCE=1
                ;;
            -h|--host)
                HOST=$2
                shift
                ;;
            -v|--verbose)
                VERBOSE=1
                ;;
            --help)
                usage
                exit
                ;;
            *)
                break
                ;;
        esac
        shift
    done
}
```

Comment: Surely you must use `"$@"` in the call to `getopt` as otherwise, the spaces within the arguments get destroyed.

Comment: +1, but `while [ $# -gt 0 ]` is unnecessary - `$1` will always contain `--` after the options, which will hit the catch-all at the end. You can use `while true` just as well.

Answer (score 0):

With slight changes you can accomplish what you desire:

```
if [[ ! $1 =~ "^--?" ]] ; then 
    echo -e "Unrecognized option: $1\n$requestHelpMessage"; exit 1;

...

case $1 in
    -*branch) # do something with $2 here
    -*batch) # do something with $2 here
    -*version) # do something with $2 here
    *) # you get the idea
esac
```

The tests allow for one or more `-`'s at the beginning of `$1`